# Cannot install crrri package on Mac OS

Tags: r, google-chrome-headless, crrri

I'm running into the following error when trying to install the headless chrom crrri package on Mac OS using  `remotes::install_github('rlesur/crrri')`:

> Downloading GitHub repo rlesur/crrri@HEAD Running `R CMD build`...
>
> - checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/6q/k8llt_rd5d3cc2tgx1fy8vth0000gn/T/RtmpinLlHt/remotes2f540ee01d2/RLesur-crrri-69c54e6/DESCRIPTION’
>   ... OK
> - preparing ‘crrri’:
> - checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
> - checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
> - checking for empty or unneeded directories Omitted ‘LazyData’ from DESCRIPTION
> - building ‘crrri_0.0.13.tar.gz’ Warning: invalid package ‘/var/folders/6q/k8llt_rd5d3cc2tgx1fy8vth0000gn/T//RtmpinLlHt/file2f549b9a34b/*
>   building ‘crrri_0.0.13.tar.gz’’ Error: ERROR: no packages specified
>   Warning message: In i.p(...) :   installation of package
>   '/var/folders/6q/k8llt_rd5d3cc2tgx1fy8vth0000gn/T//RtmpinLlHt/file2f549b9a34b/*
>   building ‘crrri_0.0.13.tar.gz’' had non-zero exit status

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what the issue was but used devtools::install_github instead of remotes and that worked.